# How to prove $a^{k\times \phi(n)+1} \equiv a\ (mod\ n$)?

Tags: totient-function

Sorry for my poor question, but I cannot prove this even if it looks so easy..
I know $a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\ (mod\ n)$, but how can I compute $a^{k\times \phi(n)}\ (mod\ n)$?

Comment: You know the crux part.  Now just use laws of exponents.  (Assuming that $a$ is coprime to $n$.)

Comment: Take the $\,\large k$'th power of $\ \large a^\phi\equiv 1\ $ (valid by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)) $\ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$a^{k\phi(n)} = \left(a^{\phi(n)}\right)^k\equiv ...$$

Comment: Thanks for the law of exponents

Comment: @baeharam No problem.

Comment: when he gets it....